# How to iterate thru table to find all values

Tags: java, selenium

I am attempting to extract and print all values associated with @class='Grp' attribute.  According to HTML, this attribute appears twice within table.  Using my code, I can find and print Text 1 value, but I cannot get Text 2 value.  I think for loop is the problem, but not sure how to fix.

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("Table"));
WebElement tbody = table.findElement(By.tagName("tbody"));
WebElement tr = tbody.findElement(By.tagName("tr"));
List<WebElement> rows = tr.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
logger.info("number of rows: " +rows.size());
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i=0; i<rows.size();i++)    
    {
        WebElement heading = table.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='Grp']"));
        if (heading.getText().trim().contains("Text"))
            { 
                logger.info("text: " +heading.getText().trim());
                list.add(heading.getText().trim());
            }
```

Html

```
<table id="Table" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<thead class="Head">
<tbody>
<tr style="height:30px">
<td class="Grp" style="background-color:#686890;white-space:nowrap" colspan="99">Text 1</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
<tr style="height:30px">
<td class="Grp" style="background-color:#686890;white-space:nowrap" colspan="99">Text 2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Try to find elements directly trough table:
     `List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("td"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.className("Grp"));
logger.info("number of rows: " +rows.size());
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (WebElement row : rows)    
{
        if (row.getText().trim().contains("Text"))
            { 
                logger.info("text: " + row.getText().trim());
                list.add(row.getText().trim());
            }
}
```